# What happens to old redirects when dns change is done

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns

I have a redirect rule at my site mobil.test.nu.

```
# For mobile devices:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|windows\ phone) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://test.nu/ [L,R=301]

# For non-mobile devices:
RewriteRule ^/?$   http://test.nu/mobil/index.htm [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.nu/mobil$1 [L,R=301]
```

Some requests are redirecting to test.nu.

I am doing the dns change of mobil.test.nu to test.nu.

I think I had to rewrite all the requests taht are coming from mobil.test.nu again in test.nu.

Could some one tell me how do I identify the requests from mobil.test.nu after dns change.

***Edit***
Identifying the host name and modifying.

```
# For mobile devices:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile\.test\.nu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|windows\ phone) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://test.nu/ [L,R=301]

# For non-mobile devices:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile\.test\.nu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$   http://test.nu/mobil/index.htm [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.nu/mobil$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add conditions that checks against the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable:

```
# For mobile devices:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mobile\.test\.nu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|windows\ phone) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mobile.test.nu/ [L,R=301]

# For non-mobile devices:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile\.test\.nu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|windows\ phone) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$   http://test.nu/mobil/index.htm [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile\.test\.nu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|windows\ phone) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.nu/mobil$1 [L,R=301]
```

Not entirely clear what your rules are supposed to be doing, as I don't think the above is going to work. But essentially the:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile\.test\.nu$ [NC]
```

will tell you whether the request is for `mobile.test.nu` or not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think, I can identify the host and write the rule as you suggested.

Comment: Please help me to check if they are correct rules are not. I edited my question.

Comment: Even after the dns change, would I be able to catch the original host using RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile\.test\.nu$ [NC]

Comment: @Patan What do you mean the "original" host? The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable is the "host" part of `http://host/path/request` of the URL

Comment: @Patan RewriteCond's **only affect** the immediately following rewrite rule, so you need to duplicate the `RewriteCond` for each rule that you need it applied to

Comment: I am doing the dns change from mobile.test.nu to test.nu. And writing the redirects in test.nu. I mean the old mobile.test.nu. Let me know if I am not clear. Please also help me in verifying my edited question with the updated answer as per your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you..In the condition # For mobile devices:, I think ! is not required right. Please suggest.

Comment: @Patan the `!` means "doesn't match", without the `!`, means it must match

Comment: Thank you. It needs to be matched for me here. :)